# Try Catch block only giving one of my throw responses

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get this to check if the keystroke typed in the textbox is a number or not. Whatever I type though gives me the same alert window. It says "The number you entered is not a number". I cannot seem to find why it is doing this.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Part 1</title>
<script>
function Numcheck(){
    var number = Number(document.getElementById("enteredChar").value)
try{
if ("number" == "") throw "was empty"
if (isNaN("number")) throw "is not a number"
if (isFinite("number")) throw "is good."
}
catch(err){
alert("The number you entered " + err);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="">
<input type="text" id="enteredChar" onkeypress="Numcheck()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is "number"?  That does not make sense.

Comment: I thought i would have to actually change the variable "enteredChar" to a number in order for this to work properly. I change the variable name also so I could follow it better when I did this.

Answer (score 4):

`if (isNaN("number")) throw "is not a number"`

The value you are passing into `isNaN` function is `"number"` which is in fact, a string and not a number.

You should change all your `"number"` to just `number`, which is the name of your variable.

Example:

```
<script>
function Numcheck() {
    var number = Number(document.getElementById("enteredChar").value)

    try {
        //This if is not required. number will never be an empty string. 
        //It will be either a valid number, or NaN.
        //if (number == "") throw "was empty";
        if (isNaN(number)) throw "is not a number";
        if (isFinite(number)) throw "is good.";
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert("The number you entered " + err);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The first `if` won't ever be true. Numbers are never empty strings. The OP needs to validate that the `value` of `document.getElementById("enteredChar")` is not `""` before the other two `if`s.

Comment: Would I need to put something before onkeypress=Numcheck then or would it be before my function?

Comment: No? On key press it should call Numcheck function.

Comment: I meant should it check for a blank field in the function Numcheck or does it need to happen down in the body of the document where my text box is located? Sorry if this is really simple stuff.

Comment: `Number("") === 0` so, if you need to verify that there is a value, you'll need to add a condition check before you do `Number(document.getElementById("enteredChar").value);` Otherwise, the other if conditions may pass when you don't expect it to pass.